# What is the -m option passed to bash when invoking the hassio_install script for?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi3

```
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/home-assistant/hassio-build/master/install/hassio_install \
    | bash -s – -m raspberrypi3
```

What does the highlighted text in the above command do?  It obviously is specific to a Raspberry Pi 3, but I'm trying to figure out if I can modify this to work for another hardware platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-m` is not interpreted or understood by bash at all, but by your `hassio_install` script.

```
case $arg in
    -m|--machine)
        MACHINE=$2
        shift
        ;;
```

...which is later used as in:

```
HOMEASSISTANT_DOCKER="$DOCKER_REPO/$MACHINE-homeassistant"
```

Which is to say, when called with `-m raspberrypi3`, the code looks for a repository named `raspberrypi3-homeassistant`, as found at https://hub.docker.com/r/homeassistant/raspberrypi3-homeassistant/

You can infer the other available names by browsing https://hub.docker.com/u/homeassistant/

Answer (score 1):

From the `bash(1)` man page:

```
   -s        If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain  after
             option  processing,  then commands are read from the standard
             input.  This option allows the positional  parameters  to  be
             set when invoking an interactive shell.

[...]

   --        A  --  signals the end of options and disables further option
             processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as  file‐
             names and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.
```

Therefore `-m` and all subsequent arguments are passed to the downloaded script.